# Is it possible to show app statistics in the app itself?

Tags: android

Working on an Android app where I would like to display the number of times the app has been downloaded. Is that possible?

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first start, you could do a "register check", that is check to see if a registration boolean has been set in your preferences.  If it hasn't been checked, do the registration process (which could increment the total count on a server somewhere), and if it has been checked, continue normally.

This solution of course won't count the number of downloads, but the number of users that have actually opened the application.

Another solution would be to use what Google gives you.  I am not sure if they have an API to retrieve the precise number, but there is public application download count data available when you are downloading an app from the Android Market.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Analytics or something similar then get the number from there. Or ping you own sever then send the results back down. Basically your going to need to have some event happen the first time a users launches an app then send that to the cloud then get the number.